# Android Studio Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

Tags: java, android

I am getting started with Parse and Facebook SDK in Android Studio. I have integrated it successfully but while running the application I am getting the following error. Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/parse/AbstractQueryController$1.class

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tanmaykulkarni.appname"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.3.0'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'
compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.4@aar'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should search for `AbstractQueryController` to check which dependency this class includes. Then you should update you script to ensure that this class is only included once. Do it like in the following example:

```
testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0') {
    //exclusions due to android.jar conflict
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
}
```